# Java regex - split string in to sections

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a parser of sorts using java. Areas of string are contained in sections using the following syntax "@some_section important stuff @some_section_end". Sections can and will be nested.

The sections are pre defined. I am looking to pull those sections out of a String, hopefully using something simple like Pattern.compile() . For example with the following dummy code...

```
<stuff>
@bank name=core
    <stuff i want>
@bankend
<stuff>
<stuff>
@bank name=arbitrary
    <stuff i want>
@bankend
<stuff>
```

... I would like the 2 items as follows (does not need to be in an array, just used to demonstrate).

```
result[0] : " name=core\n    <stuff i want>\n"
result[1] : " name=arbitrary\n    <stuff i want>\n"
```

Basically I know what needs to be done, my issue is regex. Regex does my head in at the best of the time and I am completely new to java regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java regex is largely the same as regex in other languages, other than needing to double-escape `\\\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding closure to this question.

It seams regex does not support the kind of split I am trying to do. '.' only sees valid characters and not string formatting, as such regex like '(.*?)' will only work if the total regex expression is located on a single line.

'\s' is typically used to convey both space and formatting however from the various sources I have floated this problem no one could come up with a way to combine the two to achieve the desired results (please post if you know how).

In the end I solved the problem by doing a split on the first markup. Then iterating through the results, splitting a second time on the second markup and accumulating what i needed (this actually worked pretty well for what I needed).

Shame no one will see this since people just down voted it as being '...another regex question'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "<stuff>@bank name=core    <stuff i want>@bankend<stuff><stuff>@bank name=arbitrary    <stuff i want>@bankend<stuff>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@bank(.*?)@bankend").matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536). Tried something similar my self but could not get it to work.

Comment: you might need to escape the @s

Comment: Escaping no go. The example you gave is exactly the same as others i have seen. No idea why it is not working with this particular markup. I guess I won't find out either, at least from this web site. No idea what has happened but these days the site seams more about e-chest-thumping with downvotes and closures than answering questions. Thanks for helping :)